# How to mask saved creditcard numbers in an app

Tags: accounts, credit-cards

Basically within our app users are able to save their preferred payment method.

I'm wondering if there is a best practice for displaying credit card info. So:

```
All numbers displayed: 234 1234 1234 1234
First part masked: **** **** **** 1234
Omit first numbers, mask 4, show last 4: **** 1234
Omit all masks, show last 4: 1234
```

Or any other alternative.

Comment: The majority are used in a number of major shopping applications, aside from the all numbers displayed, I'm not sure anyone can advise you of the best method, it needs to fit the requirements from a security perspective and what your customers and client needs.

Comment: I don't think it's duplicate since it's a different SE, but this should help answer your question (or at least narrow it): https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/98951/credit-card-number-masking-good-practices-rules-law-regulations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Display name, CC type, and add "Ending in" before the last 4 digits

I agree with the comments and other answers. However, when it comes to a design suggestion based on your question I would do this:

- Display the last 4 digits but with "**Ending in**" added. This assures users that those 4 digits are the last 4 of the credit card number.
- Display the **Name**. Helps in cases where users don't remember the 4 digits, and the account has multiple credit cards for different persons (i.e. User and spouse). I have an account that has three users on it and I always struggle knowing which one is mine at a glance. I do not remember the last 4 digits and the page does not display my name till I click to see more details.

**See this design:** It displays the **name** and it states that the card number **ends** with those 4 digits, and the credit card **type**. All three pieces of information play a role helping users **recognize** their credit card **at a glance**.

[image]

**Update:**

- In addition to the two points above, display the credit card type as a little icon (Visa, Mastercard...etc). Providing this piece of info allows users to faster recognize a specific card at a glance.
- Also displaying the last 4 digits only saves space. Especially important for mobile apps (usually limited on space).

Answer (score 4):

To maintain PCI Compliance you would not be able to show more than the first 6 digits (the BIN) and the last 4 digits of the card number.

More importantly though, Are you storing the credit card numbers yourself? You probably don't want to do that as it is a huge liability. Whatever payment processor you are using should have a way of tokenizing the card number (You send them the card data and they send you back a random token). You should be able to use the token to retrieve a masked version of the card number. If the processor doesn't have this feature you should probably think about using a different one.